# move a file to the current directory using shutil module

Tags: python, cmd, shutil

I know this may sound really stupid, but how can I move a file in a directory a user browsed to ( I named mine filedir) to the current directory I am in?

for example: I have a file called "pages.html" in "C:\webs".  How can I move that file to the current working directory "*.*"?

This is my code:

```
shutil.move(filedir, "*.*")
#I got errors using this code..
```

Is there another way to say current directory, other than "*.*" ?

Comment: If you get any errors using any code, it's a good idea to copy and post them. Oftentimes, a careful reading of the error message is enough to find out the source of the error.

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) specifies a directory, not a glob mask:

```
import os.path
shutil.move(os.path.join(filedir, "pages.html"), os.getcwd())
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very helpful if you posted the error message and the complete traceback. However, to get the current working directory you can use [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd). As long as `filedir` points to a file and not the directory this should work.

```
filedir = r"C:\webs\pages.html"
shutil.move(filedir, os.getcwd())
```